# Xcode with WebTrends - NSCFBoolean hasPrefix: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, webtrends

I made a game in Unity, and built it for iOS devices. The clients asked if we could implement WebTrends into the game, and so I followed [this getting started guide](https://help.webtrends.com/legacy/en/ios/docs/public_guides/Core-SDK---Getting-Started-Guide.html) for instructions on how to install it.

I was able to set it up, and got to **Step 5**, which suggests the following:

> Lifecycle events can be logged automatically by setting the
>   **wt_dc_automatics_enabled** config setting to **true**

This is where I got stumped. I then added the above setting to my `webtrends.plist`, so it now looks like this:

[image]

When attempting to build and run that, I get an error in Xcode, and the game refuses to run:

```
Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFBoolean hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11294d238
```

[This guide](https://help.webtrends.com/legacy/en/ios/docs/public_guides/Analytics---Advanced-Configuration-Guide.html) suggests setting `wt_dc_enabled` to `true` instead of `wt_dc_automatics_enabled`.

But even after replacing that in the plist, it returns the same error.

Notably, the project runs fine if I remove the `wt_dc_automatics_enabled` / `wt_dc_enabled` from the plist file, though it doesn't sent any logs, to my knowledge.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you trying making wt_dc_automatics_enabled as String type and not boolean type and add its value as YES.
Because your error says somewhere in the code hasPrefix method is called on Boolean value. hasPrefix method is defined in String class and there is no such method in Boolean class.

Comment: Yes actually, now that you mentioned it, I did try that, although with the value set to TRUE instead of YES. I'll give it a go again with YES. Due to the nature of tracking though, it might be awhile before I get an affirmative, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Tested twice, and it seems to send events for tracking now. Thanks!